# Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit

Tags: matlab

I have written code for calculating mean and skewness of an image that an Entropy has been applied to it.

```
function f = entropy_features(im)

fun0=@(x)secal(x);
emat=blkproc(im,[8 8] ,fun0); 
mu= mean(emat);
ske=skewness(emat); 

f =[mu ske];
end
```

...

```
function e = secal(im)
    e=entropy(im);
end
```

---

but I have received this error:

> Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
>   to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack
>   space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

What should I do?

Comment: How do you call this code? It definitely contains some error because blkproc passes a struct to `secal` while `entropy` expects only the image (which is part of the struct), but that does not explain the error message you receive.

Comment: I call an image and send it to entropy_features

Comment: I think the problem is with entropy(im);   when i call it separately show this error again. pleas help :-(

Comment: What does `which entropy` return?

Comment: it measures the available local information content of the image. I changed my matlab version to 2014 but still give this error

Comment: `which entropy` is a command you can run, it displays some information about the function. Can you run it and tell me the output? Just want to make sure the function is not shadowed.

Comment: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\images\images\entropy.m